# Forward to www in WordPress multisites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, forwarding

I have a WordPress multisite (using subfolders, not subdomains) in the format domain.com. For reasons of consistency and better SEO, I'd like to forward it to www.domain.com.

I've tried putting this code into `.htaccess` but I get a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# this is the code I added to forward to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm pretty sure my domain is set to without www in the WordPress settings but it won't let me see that any more now I have a multisite.

Answer (score 0):

I would try first `not` using htaccess redirect and remove the www redirect you have. Then edit your `wp-config.php` and change the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` to be your `www` domain. This way wordpress will handle the redirection.

---

Or you can try the htaccess method, but you might have some order problems, I believe with MU, the redirect needs to be the first thing. Replace domain.com with your real site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```